# Div cannot be nested inside ul and li cannot be nested inside div

Tags: html, css

In the below code i have a div inside a ul tag for making collapasable dropdown.But it throws div cannot be nested inside ul and li cannot be nested inside div.Pls help me to solve the issue.

```html
<li visible="false" runat="server" id="liMasters">
    <ul>
        <li class="heading accounts">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMasters" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </li>
        <div class="menu-item">
            <li>
                <div class="nav-item" id="SalesPrice" visible="false" runat="server">
                    <a href="/Hoard/SalesPrice.aspx" id="SalesPriceUL">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSalesPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label></a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: only li can be a direct child of a ul

Comment: Can you replace the div tags with span tags?

Comment: just move the `class="menu-item"` to the `li` and get rid of the div.

Comment: change your doctype to HTML5

Answer (score 4):

An unordered or ordered list, starting with `<ul>` tag can only contain list items (`<li>` tags). The `<li>` tags itself can contain different elements again eg. `<a>` tags.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element for more details.

Comment: this is not entirely true. li, ul support nested div in html5, it however has limited support fro html4 and below. I have used it several times

Answer (score 0):

> HTML `<ul>` Tag
>   **Definition and Usage**
>   The  tag defines an unordered (bulleted) list.
>   Use the `<ul>` tag together with the `<li>` tag to create unordered lists.

[Reference from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

If you wish, you could insert your `<div>` tags inside the `<li>` tags, that will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `li` to be `display: block` instead and it will act like a `<div>`. Then do all sorts of stuff.

```html
<li visible="false" runat="server" id="liMasters">
    <ul>
        <li class="heading accounts">
            <asp:Label ID="lblMasters" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </li>
        <li style="display: block" class="menu-item">
            <div class="nav-item" id="SalesPrice" visible="false" runat="server">
                <a href="/Hoard/SalesPrice.aspx" id="SalesPriceUL">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSalesPrice" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonable solution:

```
<li visible="false" runat="server" id="litMasters">
  <ul>
    <li class="heading accounts">
      <asp:Literal ID="litMasters" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item nav-item">
      <a href="/Hoard/SalesPrice.aspx" id="SalesPriceUL">
        <asp:Literal ID="litSalesPrice" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

All the labels are changed to literals.

Answer (score 0):

Change your doctype to either

```
<!doctype html>
```

for HTML5 which has wide support for nesting block element inside inline elements

or

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

For HTML4 and below.

Nesting divs in li, ul and dl is allowed in at least HTML5.